# when I Distribute App Xcode 13.1 crash Preparing summary

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa, ios15, distribute

**Xcode 13.1 crash  in Distribute App**

My App use charts.framework 3.3.0

My application uses charts. Framework3.3.0.
[image]

I think there is a problem here.

However, the same archive file in Xcode 12.3  it work well .

I think there is something wrong with Xcode 13.1,

however

Different projects and other projects can be packaged successfully in xcode13.1,

This makes me confused

What went wrong.

[image]

[image]

```
> Here   Xcode 13.1 crash in  Distribute App  log
Process:               Xcode [65781]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               13.1 (19466)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-19466000000000000~20 (13A1030d)
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       844664792
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [65781]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2021-11-19 09:24:46.378 +0800
OS Version:            macOS 11.6 (20G165)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        52F5D246-FDF9-90E0-35EB-5556BDC2CE93

Sleep/Wake UUID:       8D6D2E2A-D856-4FEE-8AA1-A72352EEC604

Time Awake Since Boot: 23000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       970 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        13  Dispatch queue: ConcurrentQueue: -[IDEDistributionSummaryStepViewController viewDidLoad]_block_invoke

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
Possibly stale failure hints from 2021-11-19 01:24:45 +0000:
  0: Calling block provided by:
 
  0   DVTDispatchAsync (in DVTFoundation)
  1   -[IDEDistributionSummaryStepViewController viewDidLoad] (in IDEKit)
  2   -[NSViewController _sendViewDidLoad] (in AppKit)
  3   -[NSViewController _loadViewIfRequired] (in AppKit)
  4   -[NSViewController view] (in AppKit)
  5   -[DVTViewController view] (in DVTViewControllerKit)
  6   -[IDEDistributionAssistantWindowController setDistributionStepViewController:] (in IDEKit)
  7   -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKeys:count:maybeOldValuesDict:maybeNewValuesDict:usingBlock:] (in Foundation)
  8   -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKey:key:key:usingBlock:] (in Foundation)
  9   _NSSetObjectValueAndNotify (in Foundation)
 10   -[IDEDistributionAssistantWindowController next:] (in IDEKit)
 11   -[IDEDistributionPackagingStepViewController _pipelineSucceeded] (in IDEKit)
 12   __58-[IDEDistributionPackagingStepViewController _runPipeline]_block_invoke.70 (in IDEKit)
 13   __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ (in DVTFoundation)
 14   ___DVTAsyncPerformBlockOnMainRunLoop_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
 15   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ (in CoreFoundation)
 16   __CFRunLoopDoBlocks (in CoreFoundation)
 17   __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 18   CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 19   RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
 20   ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
 21   _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter (in HIToolbox)
 22   _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 23   -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 24   -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)
 25   -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 26   -[DVTApplication run] (in DVTKit)
 27   NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 28   start (in libdyld.dylib)
 
 
 
 
ProductBuildVersion: 13A1030d
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): -[__NSCFNumber dvt_isNonEmpty]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xad7b3702d3d226f1
UserInfo: (null)
Open FDs: 54/9472
Hints: 
  0: Calling block provided by:
 
  0   DVTDispatchAsync (in DVTFoundation)
  1   -[IDEDistributionSummaryStepViewController viewDidLoad] (in IDEKit)
  2   -[NSViewController _sendViewDidLoad] (in AppKit)
  3   -[NSViewController _loadViewIfRequired] (in AppKit)
  4   -[NSViewController view] (in AppKit)
  5   -[DVTViewController view] (in DVTViewControllerKit)
  6   -[IDEDistributionAssistantWindowController setDistributionStepViewController:] (in IDEKit)
  7   -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKeys:count:maybeOldValuesDict:maybeNewValuesDict:usingBlock:] (in Foundation)
  8   -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKey:key:key:usingBlock:] (in Foundation)
  9   _NSSetObjectValueAndNotify (in Foundation)
```

Comment: it is  a Xcode Bug